# Storing a format specifier in a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

What actually happens when I do this?

```
{ 
  char * str = "%d\n";
  str++;
  str++;
  printf(str-2,300);
  return 0;
}
```

Intuitively, it appears that the number on the screen will be 300, but I want to know, what gets stored in str.

Edit: It will be great if someone can tell me, when do we actually do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: What prevents you from deducing it yourself? Is there something about `x++` or  `x-2` that needs additional explanation?

Comment: This was something that came in one of my test. I wasnt able to deduce the `str=%d` part.

Comment: Why? Do you know what `++` does?

Comment: What's the problem with you in downvoting my question? I had a doubt. I asked it. Can't I? I saw this kind of thing for the first time `str = "%d\n" and so I had a doubt? If you want to answer it, do that, if you don't atleast don't decrease the quality of the forum. You are one of those kind who want to look like "I KNOW IT ALL. YOU KNOW NOTHING".

Comment: I have not downvoted your question. I have no idea what you know and what you don't, so I'm trying to figure that out. Apparently you are new to pointers and pointer arithmetic, that's perfectly OK, I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` is a memory address, initially the address of the `%` sign of the string literal `%d\n`. This literal is created because it is in your code.

Two increments make str point to the character `\n` and when this is the case, `str - 2` is the address of the `%` sign. So printf sees the format string `%d\n`, and as usual it prints the first argument after the format string as an integer. The fact is, printf does not care about the origins of the format string. It doesn't matter if you can create it on-the-fly, or hard code it.

We don't do this generally. Sometimes you need to fiddle with a character pointer to scan a string, extract something out of a string, or to skip some prefix of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Well you are declaring a char pointer. This pointer will hold a `RAM` address from where you will write the following  bytes: `%` (1 byte) `d` (1 byte) `\n` (1byte on UNIX, 2 bytes on windows) and `\0` the null terminating byte that ends your string.

Then you increment by two your pointer value (which is the address of the first byte) then decrement by two. So basically you do nothing. Thus when calling `printf()` `src-2` will point to `%d\n` and the null terminating byte will make it exactly pass `%d\n`.
So at the end of the day what you are doing is:

`printf("%d\n", 300);` Hence the 300 output.

Answer (score 2):

`str` is a pointer on the stack. It initially points to (ie, holds the address of) the start of the string literal `"%d\n"` (this is probably stored in a read-only section of your program by the compiler).

Let's say for example the string literal (the `"$d\n"`) is stored at 0x5000. So (assuming UTF-8 or ASCII) the byte at 0x5000 is `%`, the byte at 0x5001 is `d`, 0x5002 is `\n` (the newline) and at 0x5003 it is `\0` (the terminating null character)

`str` is initially holding the address 0x5000. `str++` would increase it to 0x5001, meaning it now points to the string `"d\n"`, ie one character into the string literal `"%d\n"`. Likewise, `str++` again moves it to 0x5002, ie the string `"\n"`, two characters into the string literal `"%d\n"`. Note that all of these are still terminated by the null character at 0x5003 (how C knows when the string ends).

The `printf` call has the format string as the first argument. `str` at this point holds 0x5002, so the call is saying 'Use the format string starting at `0x5002 - 2 = 0x5000`', which turns out to be the same string that we started with.

Thus it will be the same as calling

```
printf("%d\n",300)
```

and will print out 300.

Comment: `"%d\n"` is the only string literal (it's an array of 4 chars); the pointer points to various offsets within that array.